# The wp_title in quotation marks

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a solution to this problem:

I want the wp_title on the single page to have a » mark before and a « mark after. Any suggestions?

```
<title><?php
    global $page, $paged;


    if (is_single()) {wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );}  //on this line

    else {wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );}

    bloginfo( 'name' );

    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && (is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    ?></title>
```

Comment: oh the horror.. what have you tried, except pasting this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became the solution:

```
    <title><?php
    global $page, $paged;

    if (is_single()) {the_title('&raquo;', '&laquo;');echo ' | ';}
    else {wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );}

    bloginfo( 'name' );

    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && (is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    ?></title>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your echo set to true in your wp_title function. Set it to false, and then you can wrap your titles however you like in a simple echo statement like so:

```
echo '&laquo;'.wp_title( '|', false, 'right' ).'&raquo;';
```

Comment: can be written like `echo '&laquo;', wp_title( '|', false, 'right' ), '&raquo;';`

Comment: @webarto I prefer concatenation over using commas, but yes, you can do it that way too. [And it's marginally faster](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<title>&#187<?php
global $page, $paged;


if (is_single()) {wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );}  //on this line

else {wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );}

bloginfo( 'name' );

$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && (is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

?>&#171</title>
```

Comment: This will wrap the whole title-tag. I want only wp_title to be wrapped, not the description.